# jQuery: Select an element only when it has no class name

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I use jQuery to select an element only if it doesn't have any classes?

I'm writing a page which allows the html author to override the default jQuery action by adding a class to the element.  It should be any class at all.

So the markup might be:

```
<ul>
  <li class="override"></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

I'd like jQuery to only select the second list element because it doesn't have a class.

I've looked at .hasClass(), but it seems to require a specific class name.

Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[:not() Selector – jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
$('li:not([class])')
```

Comment: Perfect!  This did just what I wanted it to.

Comment: I'm glad to help. You can accept my answer by clicking the tick button on left if it's the true answer for your question :)

Answer (score 10):

This should do it:

```
$('li:not([class]),li[class=""]')
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aMC5X/

The first part, `li:not([class])` uses the ["not selector"](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) with the ["has attribute"](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) to find any `li` elements that don't have the `class` attribute at all.

The second part, `li[class=""]` finds any `li` elements that have the attribute set to an empty string.

Comment: Interesting.  The second element is to include in the "no class" set those with an empty class name?  That's probably a good idea -- you never know.

Comment: Well if you play around with the jsfiddle I gave you can see what happens with and without the second part and decide whether you need it in your situation (in my opinion you _do_ need it).

Answer (score 2):

This should do the thing: `$('li').not('li[class]')`

Comment: Your second `li` type selector is redundant.

Comment: True. And my solution is also slower than the others xD. At least I learnt something new today

Comment: Somehow I think the single selector with the :not attribute will run faster than this one.  I read somewhere that :not was a lot faster than .not -- I'm guessing that the .not solution needs to traverse the DOM twice.

Comment: Yes, that is what it does - it traverses DOM twice. I was not sure about :not syntax so I just wrote down that.

Comment: The `.not()` method doesn't traverse the DOM twice, it filters the existing results. Which is faster might depend on the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
if (!jQuery('li').hasClass('myClass') {
    do something...
}
```