# remove jquery elements that do not have a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi can any one help me get all elements in jquery that do not have a class.

I have a list and I want to get all of the  that do not have a class and delete it

Here is the code I have so far

```
var listTableHeaders = $("ROI-List").find("th");
listTableHeaders.not(".sorting").remove();
```

I realized that there are other classes other than "sorting" as seen in this pic

[image]

I can just remove the elements that are not "sorting" or "sorting_disabled" but I am not sure if there are other classes so it would be more convenient to remove the th that do not have any class.

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Select an element only when it has no class name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042289/jquery-select-an-element-only-when-it-has-no-class-name)

Comment: `$('#ROI-List th:not([class])').remove()`. For the whole row `$('#ROI-List th:not([class])').closest('tr').remove()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter it

```
listTableHeaders.filter(function(){
   return !$(this).is('[class]');
}).remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$("ROI-List").find("th").each(function () {

   if (!$(this).prop('class').length) {

      $(this).remove();
   }   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I belive this will work for what you're trying to do:

```
$("ROI-List").find("th:not([class])").remove();
```